# Vuetify <v-data-table> - type check failed for prop "item". Expected Object, got Array

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

While learning vue.js I am building an app to upload Excel tables to the browser and display results in a more fashion and graphic way (dashboard). **This thread is intended to solve some issues that I am facing with the Excel input and table-data rendering but also to listen to any tips on the aproach** (maybe there is a more elegant way to do what I am trying). I have built the project with **Nuxt** and I am using **Vuetify** as a UI Framework.

To upload my Excel file I am using **npm read-excel-file** which I use with a function at @change within an input. Once the function is executed, the rows ff the Excel file are stored into an array of arrays (excelData) previously created at **data**.

Then I want to present the data as a table using **Vuetify v-data-table** which in its basic version, just requires the **items** and the **headers** to be called as **props**. In order to display the table just when the array has been updated I have used a **v-if** condition for **excelData.length > 0**.

As this app is intended to be used with a variety of Excel forms, I want the headers to adapt to the specific headers of every single Excel file and I am doing this by looping the first row of the imported data which is the original headers of the Excel file.

The problem that I am facing here is that even if the rendering for v-data-table is working I am getting the following error, which is not pleasant to my eyes:

**Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "item". Expected Object, got Array **

Here the code of my component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>EXCEL</h1>
        <input id="excelFile" type="file" @change="uploadExcel()"/>
        <v-data-table
            v-if="excelData.length > 0"
            :headers="excelHeaders"
            :items="excelData"
        >
        </v-data-table>`your text`
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import readXlsFile from 'read-excel-file' //requires npm install read-excel-file

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            excelData: [],
            excelHeaders: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        uploadExcel() {
            console.log("GetElementbyID")
            const input = document.getElementById('excelFile')
            readXlsFile(input.files[0]).then((rows) => {
                this.excelData = rows;
                console.log("Rows upladed, now iterate rows[0]")
                console.log(this.excelData)
                this.excelData[0].forEach((el, i) => {
                    this.excelHeaders[i] = {text: this.excelData[0][i], value: i.toString()}
            })
            })
            console.log(this.excelHeaders)
        },
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Also as I said, a different and more elegant approach would be welcome.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: No prop `item` in your snippet here. And the error is quite explanatory, try to have an object there rather than an array.

Comment: Yes, indeed but I am do not understand why. On its most basic form, v-data-table is not missing a prop in my case so I do not understand why I am having such an error.

Comment: Use your Vue devtools to inspect the state and find out exactly what you have inside of your components/state so that you are sure of what is not working properly here.